# Is there a way to prove that a Turing machine computes the function we designed it to?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

Say we design a simple Turing machine that adds two numbers together. Is there any way to *formally* prove that the machine actually computes the function we 'know' it does?

Is there a general method for all functions? Induction seems the most relevant, but will it work for any function? Any proof for this?

Comment: in your special case of the addition of two integers, a proof by induction on the numbers themselves or there number of bits should not be difficult

Comment: From the undecidability of the Halting Problem, it follows that *in general* the answer is negative.

Comment: Some functions can't be computed by any computer program. I'd bet money there are programs that correctly compute something that cannot be proven to do so correctly.

Comment: @André Nicolas : for every halting program, there is a proof that it halts. the OP starts by supposing its program halts, so I think you didn't prove anything

Comment: @Gödellingabout15 : start by asking the question for a program which can take only a finite number of different inputs : obviously, for each of these inputs there is a proof that the program computes the correct result . now, when the number of possible inputs becomes countably infinite, the question is if the number of needed  proofs to prove the program's correctness also becomes countably infinite, or if it has to stay finite.

Comment: @Gödellingabout15 : and you mean't a program which takes as input a (finite) string and outputs a (finite) string, right ? if not, for example if the program answers the infinite decimal expansion of some real number,  it is considered non halting (even if those kind of programs are in some sense computing something...) and in general analyzing it is much more complicated

Answer (score 3):

This subject is known as [formal verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) in computer science, and people have done a lot of work in it.

For a sufficiently general version of the question, and with a reasonable notion of proof, the answer is no. Any notion of proof $T$ to which the incompleteness theorems apply suffers from the following limitation. Suppose we write down a Turing machine which searches for a proof of a contradiction in $T$, and returns $1$ if it finds such a proof (and doesn't return otherwise). If $T$ is consistent, then this Turing machine is supposed to compute the partial function which never returns. But if we could prove that in $T$, then $T$ could prove its own consistency, which contradicts the incompleteness theorems. (In fact it's possible to use this kind of reasoning to prove the incompleteness theorems from the undecidability of the halting problem.)

Answer (score 2):

The only practical hope you have to be able to prove this is to develop your Turing machine (or program) carefully, making sure that you can prove that each step does its job correctly, and that the combination of steps is right. To convince a third party of its correctness, you'll have to provide the detailed reasoning behind each of the above steps.

On the other hand, Knuth famously [said](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." There have been famous failures with formal verification done by hand.